# Material-UI popover menu scrolls to bottom

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to implement a material-ui popover that contains a scrolling menu

```
      <Popover {...popoverProps}>
              <Menu className="ui-dropdown-menu">{items}</Menu>
      </Popover>
```

My relevant overridden styles are:

```
popoverStyle: {
  height: '250px',
  stroke: '#0098d1',
  fill: '#0098d1',
}
```

For some reason, this setup always has the menu scroll to the bottom when opening - is there any reason as to why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `List` and `ListItem` do not have the strange overflow issues as `Menu` and `MenuItem`